# Trying to implement a class

Tags: java

Im trying to get help with to run with my automobile compiler I chaned a few things and i have 1 error

```
public class AutomobileDescription
{ 
    /**
    Constructor to display the make, model and price the new automobile I wish to purchase
   */

    public AutomobileDescription(String carMake, String carModel, carPrice) 
    {
        make = m; 
        model = mo;
        price = p; 
    } 
     public String m =("Toyota");
     public String mo =("Camry");
     public String p =("22055");

     public String getAutomobileinfo()
     {  
     return m + mo +  p;
     Automobile myAutomobile = new Automobile(Toyota, Camry, 22055);
     System.out.println("The Make, Model and Price of the car is: m + mo + p "); 

    }
}
```

----jGRASP exec: javac -g AutomobileDescription.java

AutomobileDescription.java:7: error:  expected
    public AutomobileDescription(String carMake, String carModel, carPrice) 
                                                                          ^
1 error

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: Methods are supposed to have names, which can only have letters, numbers, or underscores.

Comment: Also, you must provide implementation to `getMake`, `getModel`, and `getPrice`.

Comment: Yes I have a problem I can get it to return the 3 mutators and instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems here:

```
public class AutomobileDescription
{ 
    /**
    Constructor to display the make, model and price the new automobile I wish to purchase
   */

public AutomobileDescription(String carMake, String carModel, /*no return type*/ carPrice) 
{
    make = m; 
    model = mo;
    price = p; 
} 
 public String m =("Toyota");
 public String mo =("Camry");
 public String p =("22055");

    public String getAutomobileinfo()
    {  
     return m + mo +  p; /*return? then why statements after this?*/
     Automobile myAutomobile = new Automobile(Toyota, Camry, 22055);
     System.out.println("The Make, Model and Price of the car is: m + mo + p "); 

    }
}
```

Solution:

```
public class AutomobileDescription{ 
/**
Constructor to display the make, model and price the new automobile I wish to purchase
*/

public AutomobileDescription(String carMake, String carModel, String carPrice) 
{
    m = make;
    mo = model;
    p = carPrice;
} 
 private String m;
 private String mo;
 private String p;

 public String getAutomobileinfo()
 {  
    return m + mo +  p;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args){
    AutomobileDescription myAutomobile = new AutomobileDescription("Toyota", "Camry", "22055");
    System.out.println("The Make, Model and Price of the car is: " + myAutomobile.getAutomobileinfo()); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Cool @shepcleveland - get a good book on Java :-).. and hack your way into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public AutomobileDescription(String carMake, String carModel, carPrice) 
                                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

You have omitted the *type* of parameter `carPrice`.  Most likely you want

```
public AutomobileDescription(String carMake, String carModel, BigDecimal carPrice)
```

Another problem...

```
 public String getAutomobileinfo()
 {  
     return m + mo +  p;
     Automobile myAutomobile = new Automobile(Toyota, Camry, 22055);
     System.out.println("The Make, Model and Price of the car is: m + mo + p "); 
}
```

The `return` statement means that the two following statements can never be reached, and this will result in a compile error after you correct the first problem.

Comment: if you see `Automobile(Toyota, Camry, 22055);` has problems too.. what's Automobile? what's Toyota, what's Camry? 22055 isn't a string.. ?? The OP seems utterly clueless about what he's upto.

Comment: You and I were writing our answers at the same time. Check the timestamps.

Comment: Then, Jim, you and I deserve a +1

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid method name:

```
public String getMake + getModel + getPrice;
```

Fix that. If you still have problems, be a little more detailed. Maybe even post the error message!

Comment: Honestly, it does show a little bit. As for my answer, a method name cannot have `+` signs like that. You can say `public String getAllDetails {` and that should work. That still doesn't mean that there's not more errors in there.